# Rewriting .each() loop as for loop to optimize, how to replicate $(this).attr()

Tags: for-loop, jquery

I running into some performance issues with a jquery script I wrote when running in IE so I'm going through it trying to optimize any way possible.  Apparently using for loops is way faster than using the jQuery .each method.  This has led me to a question regarding the equivalent of `$(this)` inside a for loop. I'm simplifying what I'm doing in my loop down to just using an `attr()` function as it gets across my main underlying question.

Im doing this with each(simplified)

```
var existing = $('#existing').find('div');
    existing.each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

And I've tried rewriting it as a for loop as such:

```
var existing = $('#existing').find('div');
for(var i = 0;i < existing.length;i++)
{
    console.log(existing[i].attr('id'));
}
```

Its throwing an error saying:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'attr'
```

Comment: Note that existing can only have one element, as the selector $('#existing') uses an ID (and not a class). And that script will only echo "existing" ...

Comment: actually it will contain a bunch of things, I just oversimplified it a bit to get my underlying point across.  Corrected.

Comment: Yes, now it makes sense with `.find('div')` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `existing.eq()` to get `jQuery` object, `existing[]` gives you `DOM` object. The function `attr()` should be called with jQuery object but not with DOM (javascript) object.

```
var existing = $('#existing');
for(var i = 0;i < existing.length;i++)
{
    console.log(existing.eq(i).attr('id'));
}
```

You can use each to get index without for loop.

```
existing.each(function(index, item){
     alert(index);
     alert(item);
});
```

Comment: thanks thats exactly what I needed.  I'm actually needing to use more methods than attr like .data() and this has fixed my errors.

Answer (score 2):

To get the id of an element just do

```
existing[i].id
```

Note that you jQuery loop would also be faster as

```
existing.each(function(){
  console.log(this.id);
});
```

More generally, you should not use `attr('id')`, especially if you're concerned by performances, as a DOM object has a property `id`.

Answer (score 1):

.I have to ask you a question before I give my answer, why would you need to perform a loop     on a single element, #existing is an Id not, therefore it's a unique element on your page.
you could simply do

```
$('#existing').prop('id');
```

In case your have more than one elements, you should be using a class or another attribute, if that is the case, you could use the following:

```
$.each('.existing',function(index,item){
    console.log(item.prop('id'));
});
```

better use prop() insted of attr() as attr is deprecated